# Prevent animation from completion when app closes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiview

I got an animation, where a car drives to the middle of the screen. When reached, the car stays there until I come back to this view, then the car drives back in again. But when I close the app when the car is in the middle of the screen and close&reopen the app, the car is hidden at the start position and NOT at the middle of the screen. I think the animation completed and carImage went to start position. How can I prevent this? My guess is, that I somehow have to remind the position of the carimage when app closes, and put the car back to this position, when app reopens, but only if the car was there before the app was closed (otherwise the animation will start at the middle of the screen, which would be bad..).

I'll show you a quick screenrecording for better understanding: 
https://vimeo.com/407626947

I got this in my ViewDidAppear:

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, animations: {
                   self.carImage.frame.origin.y += 139
                   self.carImage.frame.origin.x += 240
               }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in self.show()})
```

where "carImage" is a UIImageView with the car.png in it. I've manually put its position in the main.storyboard somewhere on the left, so that this works.

I know, its not nice at all to animate this using += 139 etc, but because I got the carImage inside a view, which is the same size at all devices, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the animations of a `UIView` block animation by removing all the animations from the view's layer:

```swift
    self.carImage.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

If this alone does not work, then you can also store the position of the view before stopping the animations and persist them while the app is in background:

```swift
    let currentPositionFrame = self.carImage.layer.presentation()?.frame
    self.carImage.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Note that the `currentPositionFrame` will be a `CGRect?`, so you will have to handle the optionals, but it should be reasonable, as you may or may not have a previous position for the `carImage` when you open the screen anyway.

UPDATE:

To keep the state of the car image while in background, I'll outline the main parts of it in the view controller:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private var oldCarPosition: CGRect? = nil  // here we'll store the position when the app goes to background

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Other setup code

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterBackground(_:)), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        // Don't forget to unsubscribe from notifications!
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }


    @objc func applicationWillEnterBackground(_ notification: Notification) {
        self.oldCarPosition = self.carImage.layer.presentation()?.frame
    }

    @objc func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let oldPosition = self.oldCarPosition else { return }
        self.carImage.frame = oldPosition
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not shure how I can use this. I tried adding the revomeAllAnimations() after I did the animation, but then the car is already at the middle of the screen when I launch the app. If I add it before the animation, it is just like before. Where should I all the let currentPositionFrame.. thing, and how exactly can I handle this?

Comment: The `let currentPosition` snippet should be added in a function called when the app goes to background. Indeed, you may not need the `removeAllAnimations()` part and only use the old position of the car. If you need, I can edit my answer to show you how to execute that code when the app goes to background.

Comment: yeah that would be nice! Thanks a lot Vlad

Comment: Glad I could help! :)